# Как PDF, полученный в Base64-строке открыть и распечатать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, base64

Создаю на стороне сервера уже готовый отчёт `PDF` со средствами `Jasperreports`, и кодирую в `Base64`. Дальше передаю всё это клиенту.

В клиенте:

```js
$.ajax({url: "reports/pdfCurStateByOwner", 
        data: {p: document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].dataset.idrju}, 
        success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //window.print(atob(data));
        },
        dataType: "text"
})
```

Что я получаю: и сервер и `console.log(data)` выдают одинаковую строку, и с помощью онлайн декодеров `base64` тоже проверил получил желанный `pdf` файл.

Теперь мне надо этот полученный байт-код распечатать и вот тут получаю не то, что получил в качестве данных, а всю страницу... Что делаю не так?

Comment: **Почитайте справку**: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, вы совсем не «байт-код» с сервера отдаёте, а `PDF`, закодированный в `BASE64`-**СТРОКУ**. Во-вторых, вы получаете при распечатке именно то, что вызвали – а именно распечатку текущего окна. В-третьих, в функцию `window.print()` нельзя передать НИЧЕГО, т.к. она ничего не ожидает. Учитесь пользоваться документацией, пожалуйста.

**РЕШЕНИЕ:**

Современные обозреватели сети имеют ограничения безопасности на открытие всплывающих окон.

**Для IE:**

> Согласно документации [IE не поддерживает `data:URL protocol` для PDF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Поэтому в отличии от остальных для него следующий код работать не будет:

```
var newWin = window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfInBase64, '_blank', 'width=500,height=300,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes');
```

Также в IE действуют ограничения безопасности на открытие всплывающих окон. Обойти их очень непросто и поэтому для IE отдельное решение через `navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob`.

**Для остальных обозревателей сети:**

> Для того, чтобы всплывающие окна открывались надо в адресной строке нажать на кнопку-оповещении о всплывающих окнах и выбрать выпадающее меню "Всегда разрешать всплывающие окна с «адрес в сети»". Такая кнопка появляется лишь тогда, если вы ещё такую кнопку для данной страницы не нажимали.

ИТАК РЕШЕНИЕ:

```
//pdfInBase64 соответствует «data» в строке «success: function (data)»
var pdfInBase64 = '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';

var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
    byteChars = atob(pdfInBase64),
    bytes = [],
    i = 0;

for (; i < byteChars.length; i++)
    bytes[i] = byteChars.charCodeAt(i);

var blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(bytes)], {type: 'application/pdf'});
// создаём object URL из Blob
var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

if(window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob)
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
else
{
    var newWin = window.open(downloadUrl, '_blank', 'width=500,height=300,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes');
    newWin.focus();
    newWin.print();//чтобы эта строка сработала страница должна быть в сети, т.е. НЕ локально.
    URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
}
```

> Этот код здесь через snippet не работает из-за ограничений в snippet. Пользователь [`@Other`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/207618/other) поделился поэтому [ссылкой на этот пример на jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/d9hakw2q/).

Обратите внимание на то, что открытие в текущем окне при помощи перемены `window.location` или с помощью `window.open` вам не подойдёт, т.к. распечатать в этих окнах уже не получится, т.к. они в этом случае перезаписываются открываемой страницей.

Можете также посмотреть: [PDF Reader на JavaScript от Мozilla](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). Но для этого нужен уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Информативно!:)

Comment: @Arthur, старался! :-) Плохо только, что вопрошающий видел мой ответ, а отклика не оставил. Видимо ответ не настолько нужным был!

Comment: Такое часто встречается на SO, уверен, вы всё равно будете в плюсе=)

Comment: Спасибо, как сказал пользователь @Arthur очень информативно!
да видел, только отвечать не было возможности )
пока сделал обычный window.open()
может проще будет если использовать библиотеку printJS, вроде там можно передавать уже готовый файл...

Answer (score 0):

window.print делает печать текущей страницы. Поэтому для печати каких-то своих данных вначале нужно сформировать отдельную html-страницу, скажем в новом окне браузера и там уже разместить кнопку/иконку, кликнув на которую можно вызвать window.print для печати (ну или через меню браузера — Печать).

Другой способ — перед печатью заменить всё содержимое текущей страницы (document.body.innerHTML) на свой вариант, после печати вернуть назад.

Comment: а просто передать данные на печать нельзя?

Comment: Вроде бы нельзя.

Comment: @MuzaffarRasulov однозначно нельзя.